# Windows 8 and BackTrack 5 R3 internet connection sharing

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet, ad-hoc-network

I have a problem. I am trying to create ad-hoc network on my laptop with Windows 8 and then connect to that network with my other laptop with BackTrack 5 R3. I was following the instructions from this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrub8Gk-lzI

Everything went well, connected two laptops with adjusted options, manually set the IP addresses, Default Gateway and Subnet Mask, pinged each other from Command Prompt, everything works like a charm, except one thing - laptop with BackTrack still has no internet connection. Do you have any suggestion on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just found my answer on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com):

Hi,

It’s possible to create a adhoc connection in windows 8.

Please follow these steps and check if it helps.
a. Hover the mouse pointer to the upper right corner and click on “Search”
b. Select Apps and type Command in the search bar.
c. Right click on Command Prompt and select Run As administrator from the taskbar.
d. In the command prompt, type the following command and hit enter.

```
netsh wlan show drivers

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<network name> key=<passkey>
```

Once the hosted network has been set to allow, you need to start the mode to create an ad hoc connection. Just enter the command below.

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

If it says “hosted network couldn’t started”, you need to disable current wireless network device and then enable it. You may also need to refresh network adapter list from Device Manger to install a virtual network device driver.

When the hosted network is started, enable ICS for newly created Wi-Fi connection, so that you can share your internet connection with others.

In order to enable ICS feature, head over to Network connections by doing the following.
a. Hover the mouse pointer to the upper right corner and click on “Search”
b. Select settings and type network connections in the search bar.
c. Click on view network connections.
d. Right click on Wi-Fi network which is connected to the Internet.
e. Click on the sharing tab.
f. Enable Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection, and then choose the newly created ad hoc connection from the list.
g. Once the internet connection is shared, check the IP address assigned to newly created ad hoc connection from TCP/IPv4 Properties.
If it doesn’t assign IP address, then run netsh wlan start hostednetwork command in CMD.

After following the above steps, you will be able to connect Wi-Fi enabled devices with your Windows 8 PC.